# Why are two srcset images loaded?

Tags: html, image, performance, responsive-images, srcset

In the context of developing responsive web templates, I use the srcset attribute to load different images depending on the current viewport size. This works fine in general. But in production mode the images are loaded from a DAM (Digital Asset Management System) where special parameters are used to scale and crop the requested images e.g.

```
<img src="{url}/s,x,586,y,0/{img_id}"
     srcset="{url}/s,x,293,y,0/{img_id} 293w,
            {url}/s,x,440,y,0/{img_id} 440w,
            {url}/s,x,586,y,0/{img_id} 586w"
     sizes="(max-width: 520px) 100vw, (max-width: 1010px) 40vw, 15vw" />
```

The problem is: now every image is loaded twice (440w and 586w).
Is this a caching problem?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce that issue. In my test (Firefox 49) only the 293w version was loaded. Can you provide a link to the affected page? Which browser and version did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly fine, the browser should load only one of the images, unless you resize the window or maybe rotate a tablet.